# Validate DataGridView on menu item click

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, validation

Hi I have a windows form containing a menu bar, tool strip and a DataGridView control.
I am using VB.Net.

I have a save button on the tool strip and a save menu item. I need validation to run before save occurs. My problem is that if a cells value is changed and then either of the save buttons is clicked, validation does not run and so the new value is not saved.

I have had a look at the events on the DataGridView such as the 'leave' event however none seem to do what I want. I.e. 'leave' does not run when either of the save buttons is clicked.

Does anyone know of a way I can run my validation code when one of these buttons is clicked (or any other button).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that clicking on either a button on a `ToolStrip` control or an item on a `MenuStrip` control does *not* cause the `Validating`/`Validate` events to be raised by the currently selected control. This is by-design. Interacting with menus and toolbars does not cause the currently selected control to lose focus, which means that validation is never triggered.

If you think about it carefully, this even makes sense. Imagine that your validation logic required each cell to contain a value (i.e., it prevented cells from being left blank or empty). If the validation event was triggered each time that a user tried to select an item from a menu or toolbar, they couldn't even "Paste" anything into the cell!

You'll have to add a bunch of ugly, additional logic to your form if you insist on overriding this behavior, and you run the risk of seriously annoying your user. Suffice it to say that I don't recommend it.

The better solution is to extract your validation logic into a separate method, and call it manually at the beginning of the event handler method for each menu/toolstrip item that you want to trigger validation. Alternatively, you could raise the `LostFocus` event for your `DataGridView` control at the beginning of your Save toolstrip button click event handler using the [`InvokeLostFocus` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokelostfocus.aspx). Something like:

```
InvokeLostFocus(myDataGridView, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, calling my Form's "Validate" function from within the menu's click event was enough to do what I needed, which included forcing the grid's validation events to fire.

Comment: Validate() didn't work for me, but ValidateChildren() did.  It's perhaps not the cleanest solution, but the only way I've been able to force the grid to validate without programatically trying to change cells, which would be an even worse solution.

Answer (score 0):

While validation occurs on controls like the `TextBox` just after the `Leave` event is fired, the `DataGridView` control only performs validation while in edit mode, and only on a per-cell basis.

You can handle the `CellValidating` event on the `DataGridView` to capture the moment when the current cell undergoes validation - this event would be fired if focus moved from the grid to your save button. If the cell's value is invalid, you can set the `Cancel` property on the `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` object to `true`.

Comment: While all of this is correct, it still doesn't solve the asker's problem. Clicking on a `ToolStrip` item won't actually trigger the validation events because the currently selected cell remains selected. See my answer for details.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have realised that. I was exploiting that very behaviour recently in order to implement a custom drop-down control :P

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and none of the responses on various forums did the trick for me. In my case I had multiple grids on the form. And even some grids within other UserControls. So I created the following routines, and call CommitGridEdit() in the relevant ToolStrip click events. It seems to do the trick for me.

```
Public Sub CommitGridEdit(ByVal frm As Form)
    ' Clicking on a ToolStrip menu item will not cause the grid to end editting the current cell.
    ' So we have to find if any grid is in edit mode and do this ourself.
    Dim grid As DataGridView = GetFocusedGrid(frm)

    If grid Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not grid.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then
        If grid.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode Then
            grid.EndEdit()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetFocusedGrid(ByVal ctl As Control) As DataGridView
    For Each c As Control In ctl.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is DataGridView AndAlso c.ContainsFocus Then
            Return c
        ElseIf c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            Dim c2 As Control = GetFocusedGrid(c)
            If Not c2 Is Nothing Then Return c2
        End If
    Next c
    Return Nothing
End Function
```